# Compare two users' placement in Active Directory hierarchy

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I need to compare two usernames in Active Directory (with LDAP in VB.NET) and return whether the second name is "lower" in the company hierarchy than the first name.  If the second user is at the same level as or above the first user, I should get a false.

The monstrosity I'm currently using takes the first user's "directReports" list and recursively creates a list of all of *their* direct reports and so on, and checks that final, flattened list for the second user's name. It works, but if the company president is the first user, it takes upwards of two minutes to complete. Extremely inefficient, I know, but so far it's the only thing I've been able to piece together.

It seems odd to me that I haven't been able to find a solution to this here or elsewhere, which tells me one of two things:  1.) I haven't found the proper combination of search terms, or 2.) There is likely a much different, much easier method of accomplishing what I need!

Comment: Can't you use the "manager" attribute to work your way up from the second user and return true if you find the first user?

Comment: Egads.  Forehead-to-desk slam of the decade.  Sometimes you just need a slightly different perspective...  Thank you very much!